# How should I reference to a function/void of the "grandparent" class in Java?

Tags: java, class, reference, extends, super

I know that I can reference to a function/void of my parent class with super.
But what about my grandparent? super.super.void/function?

Comment: You can reference any method from anywhere in the inheritance hierarchy by calling it directly.

Comment: You can't do super.super or equivalent in Java. Your best and only option aside from redesign has been given by @SLaks

Comment: Then what's the point of the super reference?

Comment: @hazazs imagine you are overidding a `method()` and you want to invoke the one you are overriding from within that method (which is usually a good thing to do).  Your first statement would be `super.method();`  Super is also used in certain `generic` constructs to support typing requirements

Comment: I invoke it in order to expand the overwritten method with additional commands (for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your class and your parent class don't overwrit it you can simply call it. If it has the right visibility (protected,public or if your subclass is in the same package even package-private)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have something like this:
A extends B which extends C and C has a method `.method()`

So, in this case, B has inherit all the C's methods, and so if A wants to call a method that is in C, it just need to call `super.method()`, which will call `B.method()`, which (if it's not been overwritten) is the method that is being inherited by C (obviously check the visibility)

Comment: If A wants to call a method in C and it is accessible, all A needs to do is call it.  `a.method();` where `a` is an instance of `A`

Comment: @WJS if you are ina class method, how can you call A.method? my B.method notation is just for explanation purpose, but in reality A will call super.method()

Comment: If `A extends B and B extends C`, then an instance of A can call any method in the hierarchy as long as it is accessible.  That is all the explanation that is needed and it was provided in the comments.